# Async method doesn't retrieve information in correct order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

In Vue.js, I have this method:

```js
async deleteItemFromDb(item_id) {
      const dbUser = this.settings.db_user
      const dbCreds = this.settings.db_creds
      const dbUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:9878/items/"

      const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(dbUser + ":" + dbCreds)
      }

      let getUrl = dbUrl + item_id
      const projectData = await fetch(getUrl, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers,
        mode: "cors",
        credentials: "include"
      })

      let delUrl = dbUrl + await projectData._id + "?rev=" + await projectData._rev
      const deleteItem = await fetch(delUrl, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: headers,
        mode: "cors",
        credentials: "include"
      })

      console.log("Item deleted from DB:", deleteItem.data)
}
```

What happens here is that the `projectData` doesn't report any errors, so the fetch method gets launched properly, but the `deleteItem` comes back with something like:

```
DELETE http://127.0.0.1:9878/items/undefined?rev=undefined 404 (Object Not Found)
```

Also, the `console.log` returns `undefined` as the data.

I assume the data doesn't manage to come back soon enough to form the `delUrl` correctly. But what is the correct order, or rather which variables should be marked here as `await`?

Comment: Why are there awaits here? `let delUrl = dbUrl + await projectData._id + "?rev=" + await projectData._rev` those are not correct, remove them. Now you probably want to read JSON and not the raw fetch request

Comment: what does `console.log(projectData)` log? Actually you don't need the await a second time. fetch returns a Promise, if this is resolved, await has done it's job and the result is stored in the projectData variable. If you expect JSON data to be returned, you need to process that. `.then(res => res.json())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fetch()` needs to be followed up with a call to `.json()` (or one of the [other functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#methods) if you're expecting a different data format)

```
const response = await fetch(getUrl, {  
  method: "GET",
  headers: headers,
  mode: "cors",
  credentials: "include"
})
const data = await response.json();
let delUrl = dbUrl + data._id + "?rev=" + data._rev
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the await from the below statement

```
      const projectData = await fetch(getUrl, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers,
        mode: "cors",
        credentials: "include"
      }).json(); // change added

      let delUrl = dbUrl + projectData._id + "?rev=" + projectData._rev; // removed await
```